# Oozie common property/configration for multiple workflows

Tags: workflow, oozie

I have a around 10 oozie workflow.Each workflow.xml is in a separate folder.All the workflow hava some common configuration property like jobtracker,name node,defaultqueue etc.
Can you please tell me the best possible solution to have a common property/xml, so that i dont need to use the same parameter in each workflow.xml

Comment: should I add a config-default.xml file the each workflow folder?

Comment: is there any other best solution apart from the above?

Comment: seem like you need to create one for all workflow and include it for each workflow - did you try it ? I think this can be some help http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-shorten-your-oozie-workflow-definitions/

Comment: the solution is good for common configuration within in single worklfow which has multiple action.I am looking for a common config file which can be used across multiple workflows.